# Is it expected that a ble device might not advertise services?

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using flutter reactive ble to connect to a bluetooth device with a specific serviceId.

The library allows me to scan for devices with a specific service id...

```
var stream = _ble.scanForDevices(withServices: [ myServiceId ] , scanMode: ScanMode.lowLatency);
```

This scan ends up yielding no results.

If I do not provide a serviceId on the scan, I can call discover services on all scanned devices, and then subsequently find the service I am looking for...

```
List<DiscoveredService> services = await _ble.discoverServices(_device.id);
```

Is this a valid scenario? Does the bluetooth device have to do something special like advertise the service, to have scans parse by serviceId? Is there such thing as a advertised service, vs a discovered service?

Comment: If you use the app nRF Connect (or any other BLE debug app), you can see the full advertisement data. The advertising data space is limited, and it's not mandatory to include all the service uuids there.

Comment: But if you want to connect via a service id, the service uuid will need to be advertised there....correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.